# LUA 5.1 how do i get the calling variable from a function?

Tags: lua, lua-5.1

```lua
function newpos(xScale, xOffset, yScale, yOFfset)
    print(f.Position)
end

local f = {}
f.Position = 1
f.Size = newpos(1, 0, 1, 0)
f.Filled = true
f.Visible = true
```

how do i get the f table from newpos?

Comment: You have to pass it in as a parameter.

Comment: I can't make sense of your question. what's a calling variable? why is f being index in newpos? it is a nil value. you cannot index a nil value.  please explain what you are trying to achieve. as you're currently asking about a http://xyproblem.info

Comment: You can move the line `local f = {}` above the `newpos` definition.

Answer (score 0):

> how do i get the f table from newpos

If you want to get a table from a function that function needs to return that table.

Let's say you want to create a table that represents a 2d point:

```
function newpos(x, y)
  local p = {
    x = x,
    y = y,
  }
  return p
end
```

Then you can do something like

```
local origin = newpos(0, 0)
print(origin.x, origin.y)
```